# Party members stopped following main character in Neverwinter Nights 2

Tags: pc, neverwinter-nights-2

I am playing NWN 2, and recently the party members stopped following main character when I am walking around. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. You accidentally turned on puppet mode, which means none of the characters will move or act unless you command them to.  Turn that mode off by clicking on the icons to the left below the portraits.
2. You told them to hold position.  To undo this, order your party members to follow you through the quick commands menu.  (Default key is V if I remember correctly to bring it up)

Comment: Option (2) did the job, cheers!